# Does total packets length in tcp buffer can exceed allocated buffer size?

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

It is known that `getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &opt_val, &opt_len);` returns the twice of the size of the tcp buffer that was allocated before in `setsockopt()`.

(As written in `man 7 tcp`:

`Note that TCP actually allocates twice the size of the buffer requested in the
       setsockopt(2)  call,  and  so a succeeding getsockopt(2) call will not return the same size of buffer as requested in the setsockopt(2) call.  TCP
       uses the extra space for administrative purposes and internal kernel structures,`)

So if I do `setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (int *)&buf_size, sizeof(buf_size))` for `buf_size = 256K`, `512K` will be allocated and returned in `getsockopt()`.

I want to count the current amount of bytes in `tcp buffer`. for that I'm counting the length of each packet in the queue (`sk->sk_write_queue->len`) while `sk` is `struct sock *sk`.

It happens that there are times which the length returned is bigger than `256K`. (for instance, I got `294879` bytes that is `32735` bytes more than `256K`).

Why does it happens?
Does it includes `"extra space for administrative purposes and internal kernel structures"` as the `getsockopt(.., SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, ..)` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 512K actually gets allocated, buffering 294879 bytes is not that surprising. 
On linux, when you set the SO_SNDBUF, the kernel simply doubles that amount.

If you want the socket buffer to be 256k, call setsockopt() with 128k.

Now, the buffers used are not purely for your data, the skb's and other data structures the kernel needs are allocated in these buffers, which is the "administrative overhead", how much overhead this amounts to depends on how the kernel slices up the data you give it - so reserving exactly 256k of buffer space for only the data you send from userspace is a rather hard if not practically impossible task.

Comment: Thanks, So does the returned length not contains any "administrative overhead" ? only the data itself?

Comment: @hudac I believe it is the user data only, though it'll certainly depend on how you calculate the lengths and where in the protocol stack you are.

Comment: Note also that there's the SIOCOUTQ ioctl() you can perform on a TCP socket which should give you the amount of bytes in the TCP socket buffers (that will be the amount of data not yet sent + the amount of data sent but not yet acknowledged by the peer)